Limit and System of Equation
if $\;f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c\;$ intercept at y-axis point $(0,1)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)}{x-1} = -4$, then the value of $\;\frac{b+c}{a}\;$ is ...
So, I tried by plug in $x = 0\;$ and $\;y = 0$.
$$\;f(0) = a(0)^2 + b(0) + c\;$$
$$c = 1$$
Then, using derivative to evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \;\frac{f(x)}{x-1} = -4$$
$$\frac{2ax + b}{1} = -4$$
$$2a + b = -4$$
Is $\;2a + b = -4\;$ and $\;c = 1\;$ equation enough to form $\;\frac{b+c}{a}\;$ equation? or we have to get the $a$ and $b$ value too? But, in what way we could get the $a$ and $b$ value?

Edit(after @Khosrotash'answer)
So, because of
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \;\frac{f(x)}{x-1} = -4$$
is actually $\;0/0$
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \;\frac{f(1)}{1-1} = \frac{0}{0}$$
$$f(1) = 0$$
$$a + b + c = 0$$
$$a + b + 1 = 0$$
$$a + b = -1$$
By eliminating the equation, I get $a = -3$, $b = 2$, and $c = 1$. So, the value of $\;\frac{b+c}{a}\;$ is equal to $-1$.

But I'm still confused, how do you know that $\lim_{x→1}\frac{f(x)}{x−1}=−4$
is $0/0$
not$∞/∞$
? is it because the $x−1$
value is $0$
, so it can be assume that $\lim_{x→1}\frac{f(x)}{x−1}=−4$
is $0/0$
? –

I took the liberty of editing your post to clarify by showing the edited part. As for your question, you're there

@Stéphane Jaouen Hey! Thank you for editing my post!

As a hint: With respect to $$\lim_{x\to 1} \;\frac{f(x)}{x-1} = -4
$$ must be $\frac {0}{0}$ so you will have another equation . It means $$f(1)=0 \\ \to a+b+c=0$$ put it next to $$c=1, 2a+b=-4$$and solve the system of equations
Remark: Use of l'hopital's rule is possible when $\frac{0}{0}$

Hey! Thank you for the hint! I already updated the question with the answer that I come with, can you check on it? But I'm still confused, how do you know that $\lim_{x\to 1} ;\frac{f(x)}{x-1} = -4$ is $0/0$ not $\infty/\infty$? is it because the $x - 1$ value is $0$, so it can be assume that $\lim_{x\to 1} ;\frac{f(x)}{x-1} = -4$ is $0/0$?

@Khosrotash : I took the liberty of editing OP's post to include his last question and "solution-verification"-tag. I hope that's not clumsy of me. My goal was to clarify his post by showing the edited part

Since the denominator of the fraction:
$\dfrac{f(x)}{x-1}$
Approaches $0$ as $x\to1$, for the limit to converge it must be $[0/0]$ (if the numerator approached anything other than $0$ the limit would obviously diverge). So $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to1$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, this means that:
$f(1) = a + b + c = 1$
And this is the last equation you need to solve the system. You can just substitute $b=-a$ in the second equation and you're done.
